# halt the main function from returning a value

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Consider the following example

```
function [B] = testtag
f = figure(1)
B = 1;
store_x = []
btn1 = uicontrol(f,'Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'tagpoints',...
        'Position', [5 5 60 20],...
        'Callback', @tagdata);   
btn2 = uicontrol(f,'Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'storeandreturn',...
        'Position', [70 5 80 20],...
        'Callback', @returnvalue);
y_axis = [randi([0,20],1,100)  randi([20,40],1,100) randi([0,20],1,100)];
x_axis = 1:300;
ax = subplot(1,1,1)
hplot = plot(x_axis,y_axis);
n = 1;

    function tagdata(source,callbackdata)
       [x,  ~] = ginput(2);                                              %saving indexs of the x axis or the time stamp of the place clicked 
       tic;  
       store_x(n:n + 1) = x(1:2);
       n = n +2;
       zoom on

    end    
    function returnvalue(source,callbackdata)
        B = store_x
        close(figure(1))
    end   
end
```

It plots some random data and adds two buttons in the end of the plot , when one button is pressed it tags two data points in a pair and store them in a matrix , after that the user can zoom in and tag some more pair points , and the second button stores all the datapoints to the main return variable and closes the figure  , now here is my problem the function will obviously return '1' in the output because the main function ends before the callback has been even called but what I want is the function to halt until all the datapoints have been stored in the return variable and the figure closes when second button is pressed without using a while loop ofcourse), is there some way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `uiwait` to stop the primary function returning.

Add

```
uiwait(f)
```

At the end of your main function -> that will wait until the figure closes (or a `uiresume(f)` is issued) to continue and hence return your data.